# Problem Compiling Google WebRTC API

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-conferencing

Has anyone tried to build this project:

```
http://sites.google.com/site/webrtc/reference
```

I can not seem to build the peerconnection_client.exe file.
If somebody has any idea, please suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem is solved. I had to include these librares:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86
```

However the code provided by them is of no use from web dev perspective. For desktop app, it is helpful as of now.